# Is it bad form to call `createElement` manually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using JSX everywhere in my React project because of course I am.
But there are a few instances where using `createElement` is particularly helpful.

Here's one such example, which is representative of my typical use case.
I have a reasonably-sized string that I want to display in a `<pre>` tag, except that I want all instances of the `\r` (`0x0D`) character to be displayed as `<CR>` *in a different color*. 
I can easily accomplish that as follows

```
const splitOnCR = stdin.split("\r");

const joinerStyle = {
    color: "#337ab7",  // Bootstrap primary color
}
const joiner = <tt style={joinerStyle}>{"<CR>"}</tt>;

let parts = new Array(splitOnCR.length * 2 - 1);
for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0) {
        parts[i] = splitOnCR[i / 2];
    } else {
        parts[i] = joiner;
    }
}

const style = {
    fontFamily: "monospace",  // override Menlo or whatever
};
return React.createElement(
    "pre",
    {style},
    ...parts,
    <span>&nbsp;</span>,  // show final newlines, if any
);
```

which indeed produces

[image: the result of the above code, showing both a correctly processed carriage return and the literal text "<CR>"; the latter is not colored]

The alternative that I see here would be to generate an individual `<tt>` or `<span>` or whatever for every character in the string and then render them all in an array.
I don't want to do that.
It would make me sad.

I've inspected the DOM while changing the string, and it looks like React will happily change only the last text node as I append to the string, and it only creates a single extra `<tt>` when I add a carriage return. This is as I  expected (and hoped).

But I can also imagine that this variadic call to `createElement` might confuse the diffing algorithm in some way—after all, we usually need `key`s when rendering out arrays.
I just don't know what that is or what the effect would be.

So—is this safe? Is it good? Any other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

JSX is just syntactic sugar for `React.createElement`. React really doesn't care (or know) whether you wrote `React.createElement` manually or not.

> But I can also imagine that this variadic call to `createElement` might confuse the diffing algorithm in some way—after all, we usually need keys when rendering out arrays.

Yes and no. What you are doing would be equivalent to this in JSX

```
<parent>
  <child1 />
  <child2 />
</parent>
```

I.e. you simply have an element with multiple "direct" children, instead of passing the children an array. You probably have seen this before, because this is pretty common, so your solution is not worse for React than using JSX this way.

Keep in mind that *any* element can have a key. React just enforces it if you pass an array.

Now the question is, what advantages does using `key` have (see next section).

> I just don't know what that is or what the effect would be.

You probably want to read https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html. Quoting the relevant part:

> ### List-wise diff
>
> #### Problematic Case
>
> In order to do children reconciliation, React adopts a very naive approach. It goes over both lists of children at the same time and generates a mutation whenever there's a difference.
>
> For example if you add an element at the end:
>
> ```
> renderA: <div><span>first</span></div>
> renderB: <div><span>first</span><span>second</span></div>
> => [insertNode <span>second</span>]
> ```
>
> Inserting an element at the beginning is problematic. React is going to see that both nodes are spans and therefore run into a mutation mode.
>
> ```
> renderA: <div><span>first</span></div>
> renderB: <div><span>second</span><span>first</span></div>
> => [replaceAttribute textContent 'second'], [insertNode <span>first</span>]
> ```
>
> There are many algorithms that attempt to find the minimum sets of operations to transform a list of elements. Levenshtein distance can find the minimum using single element insertion, deletion and substitution in O(n2). Even if we were to use Levenshtein, this doesn't find when a node has moved into another position and algorithms to do that have much worse complexity.
>
> #### Keys
>
> In order to solve this seemingly intractable issue, an optional attribute has been introduced. You can provide for each child a key that is going to be used to do the matching. If you specify a key, React is now able to find insertion, deletion, substitution and moves in O(n) using a hash table.
>
> ```
> renderA: <div><span key="first">first</span></div>
> renderB: <div><span key="second">second</span><span key="first">first</span></div>
> => [insertNode <span>second</span>]
> ```
>
> In practice, finding a key is not really hard. Most of the time, the element you are going to display already has a unique id. When that's not the case, you can add a new ID property to your model or hash some parts of the content to generate a key. Remember that the key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique.

Comment: "What you are doing would be equivalent to this in JSX"—well, not quite; a better analogy would be if your `<child2 />` were sometimes just not there. The usual way to do that in JSX is to write `{cond && <child2 />}`, but in that case the argument is still present, just possibly falsy.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have read the `key` docs (many times! `:)`). I guess my underlying question is: if React can solve this problem with my use case, why doesn't that solution generalize to make `key`s entirely unnecessary?

Comment: Well, I simplified. What makes you think React performed the optimal tree transformation without keys? The docs are pretty clear about what `key` is used for. Not sure what else to add to that.